# Build Project inside docker container and share folder in mounted

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose, share, mounted-volumes

I use docker-compose to build my containers and on a state I checkout private repository and I build the project inside container with composer.

I have the following structure

```
- docker-project
-- docker //here I keep the containers
--- apache
---- Dockerfile // the content what I posted
-- docker-compose.yml
-- src //this is the mounted folder where I can work on project
```

After build I would expect that the build project would show up in the mounted folder but instead I get empty folders here is my compose yml

```
     apache:
        container_name: apache2
        build:
          context: ./docker/apache

        ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
        links:
        - database
        restart: always
        volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/
        - ./docker/logs/apache2/:/var/log/apache2/
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
        - ./docker/apache/sites/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

and here I have the docker file

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    openssl \
    openssh-server \
    sendmail \
    sendmail-bin \
    mailutils \
    libicu-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libz-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev  \
    g++ \
    libxml2-dev \
    git \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install various PHP extensions which are required to build project
RUN docker-php-ext-configure bcmath --enable-bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_pgsql --with-pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure mbstring --enable-mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-configure soap --enable-soap \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        json \
        intl \
        mbstring \
        mcrypt \
        mysqli \
        pcntl \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        soap \
        sockets \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd

##install xdebug and enable it. We need this for php unit coverage
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN yes | pecl install mongodb \
&& docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN update-ca-certificates

# install composer to can install dependencies
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"


RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
RUN rm -rf /var/www/project
WORKDIR /var/www/
RUN git checkout path/to/repo
RUN ls -l /var/www
WORKDIR /repo
RUN composer install
RUN ls -l
```

on `docker-compose build` I see that the project will be builded but on 
`docker-compose up`the folder is empty

What I'm missing in this case?

Comment: which folder you talking about here? and from which folder you ran `docker-compose up`?

Comment: I made an edit which is reflecting the way hows my docker folder looks like

Answer (score 1):

You are mounting a volume on `/var/www` when starting the container.

`/var/www` will be the same as `./src/www` on the host machine, replacing anything that was added to `/var/www` during the build of the image.

Consider using the [composer docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/composer/) or make sure to install the dependencies to another directory. Check out the `vendor_dir` key in [composer.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir)

Example:
composer.json

```
{
 "require": {

 },
 "config": {
   "vendor-dir": "/var/www/vendor/"
 }
}
```

Docker image build:

```
...
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/vendor/
COPY composer.json /var/www/vendor/
RUN cd /var/www/vendor/ && composer install
RUN mkidr -p /var/www/app
...
```

docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/app
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, Is not clear how to deal with this. I'm quite new to docker. In this case at what point would I checkout the project and install composer dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for update, but is still not clear for me how do I deal with an existing php project which has the dependencies. As you see I check out project from gitlab

Comment: Why would you mount a volume if you add the source from a repo?

Comment: for other projects

Comment: anyway, if you mount a volume ontop of a directory anything that was there during the image build will be gone. Use multiple DIFFERENT folders if you want to bloat your container with multiple projects

Comment: OK I got the idea, but how do I use the composer on a project like laravel?

Comment: You’d usually check out your source code _outside_ of Docker.  In compiled-language environments it’s not uncommon to build your application outside of Docker too.  There’s not requirement to do everything from inside the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I could give a way of currently we are working. Rather cloning the repo like this what we do, we clone the repo in the local machine.

- You have standard docker image that you have created from
  `php:7.1-apache` with required softwares that you need to run the project.
- Then you clone your project to you host machine.(think into src folder)
- You run the `composer install` locally.
- Then as you have defined the `docker-compose.yml` mount your `src` folder into `/var/www/`